# Living in Australia after studying

Tags: immigration, student-visa, australia

I applied to an Australian university and got rejected because I do not meet the [GTE requirements](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/stud/more/genuine-temporary-entrant). I'm sure it was because I was honest with them and said I wanted to live in Australia after my studies.

Here is what the GTE requirement says:

> An applicant needs to show they are coming to Australia temporarily to gain a quality education.

At the same time:

> The GTE requirement is not designed to exclude those students who, after studying in Australia, go on to develop the skills required by the Australian labour market and apply to obtain permanent residence.

Does this mean that I can apply for work visa only after I work for some time in my home country (or some other country)? Is `student visa -> work visa` forbidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not make that requirement. Although I absolutely see how it can be read that way. It specifically acknowledges that it's ok for circumstances to change and for people to follow a legal path to permanent residence.

The page you linked also says the gte test helps "identify those applicants who are using the student visa program for motives other than gaining a quality education" so taken overall, they felt that your application was more focused on residence and employment than on education.

The rest of the page, and the linked ministerial direction which you are advised to read, give the gte assessor guidance on what to consider.

Very generally, if you are someone who is fortunate enough to have other attractive options in life besides migrating to Australia, you are more likely to be accepted.

Comment: Ohh. So what matters is the "intention" at the time of getting the visa. And this "intention" does not need to be the real intention which includes the future plans. I guess I exposed more information than I should've.

Comment: I am absolutely not suggesting you should lie about your intentions. Please read the full ministerial direction that is linked from that page. All applicants should read it. It explains fully what is being considered.

Comment: I read it. From what I understood, the most important thing is that the applicant has a strong incentive to return to their home country. They might have plans to immigrate to Australia after studies but still can have strong incentives to return. Immigration after studies is irrelevant to the student visa. So talking about it will be harmful as it would show that I no longer want to go back to home country. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @WingerSendon I think their point is just to ensure that a *student* visa is indeed issued for people who want to "study". There are indeed many people who after obtaining a student visa actually don't go to classes at all and instead work (illegally) and stay for a long period of time. If you indeed value the program that you applied to and is focused on finishing it before any future plans I don't think there should be issues. If you're like "well the program is more like a pretext for me to stay here long-term and I don't actually care much about it" they'd probably not be satisfied.